# woocommerce: add value to a product attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I add value to a woocommerce attribute through code?
I have created an attribute called 'Dispatch time' (taxonomy: pa_dispatch) and now I want to add value to a particular product's Dispatch attribute.

How to do this programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer, you need to use [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) to set the terms of object of a taxonomy,

```
wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append);
```

Where, $append can be `true` or `false`, if true, the tag will be appended to existing tag, if false, the tag is replaced.

In my example,

```
wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, '2 Business Days', 'pa_dispatch' , false);
```

Here, the `pa_dispatch` is the woo-commerce taxonomy.

Comment: thank you. where in your functions.php did you put this? and what is $object_id?

Comment: @nicmare Put it where you want to change the value, but if you put this statement in functions.php directly, then the function will run every time any file loads! Also, the $object_id is nothing but the product's id, ie., post ID of that particular product.

Comment: of course i would fire it with save_post hook. i will give it a try. thank you

Comment: it is not working for me, $product->get_attribute('my_attr'); return 'val1 | val2' but wp_set_object_terms( $product->ID, 'val3', 'my_attr' , false); returns invalid_taxomony. ideas?

Comment: @user2867106 Is your 'my_attr' a woocommerce taxonomy? how did you create 'my_attr'?

Comment: @Rao `wp_set_object_terms` doesn't update the text fields, do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add value to an attribute. You need to make the product variable, create a variation, and assign it with the attribute. Now in this variation you can assign a value.

[image: Attributes Configuration]

[image: Variations Configuration]

**Read mode:**

1. http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PX8MWBOAeo

**EDIT:**

After more clarification on the question, here is an updated solution.

Add the below function to your functions.php. Call it on the appropriate hook and pass the product ID as well as the attribute values.

```
function se19519561_set_attributes($post_id, $attributes) {

    //Type attribute
    $product_attributes['type'] = array(
        //Make sure the 'name' is same as you have the attribute
        'name' => htmlspecialchars(stripslashes('Dispatch Time')),
        'value' => $attributes,
        'position' => 1,
        'is_visible' => 1,
        'is_variation' => 1,
        'is_taxonomy' => 0
    );

//Add as post meta
update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: no, that's not what I am trying to achieve, I am able to add the value through GUI, but I want to do this programmatically in php.

Comment: ie., I want to add the value, '3 business days' to a particular product's 'Dispatch time' attribute through php function.

Comment: Do you want to add the attribute on the fly when the product page is accessed or do you want to add this to all the products at once?

Comment: I have a set of product post ids, for which I want to add the dispatch time values, I don't need to create the attribute, its already created. I just want to add values to those attributes for some products.

Comment: Hi, posted an edit into the answer with a function. Hope this helps.