# Create new product attribute programmatically in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

How can I create attributes for WooCommerce from a plugin?
I find only :

```
wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append);
```

From [this stack-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518878/woocommerce-add-value-to-a-product-attribute)

But this approach required id of some product. I need to generate some attributes not attached to any products.

Comment: But a default attribute *is* product-specific, so I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I need generate some default attributes  here http://joxi.ru/gmvegqWt185Vra when my plugin activated.
And I can do it manually, but I want - automatically

Comment: But what do you mean by default attribute? Since as I mentioned, a term can only be the default for a specific product.

Comment: When i create attribute like category, i not attached him to any of products right?
So i need GENERATE few attributes without binding to product.

Comment: Ah ok.... so I think you want to create a term. In which case you will need [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term)

Comment: second param this func is taxonomy, what taxonomy is attributes? 
regular taxonomy for categoies taxonomy=category  Product category is taxonomy=product_cat. i can't find what taxonomy is attributes ?
Look - i`ts a page  or i'm wrong? http://joxi.ru/xAee01MtX7WYAy

Comment: See my answer below. Attributes isn't a taxonomy in its own right. Each attribute (ex: color, size, font) is its own taxonomy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To create a term you can use [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term)

like so:

```
wp_insert_term( 'red', 'pa_colors' );
```

where `colors` is the name of your attribute. The taxonomy name of an attribute is always prepended by `pa_`.

**Edit** Attributes are merely custom taxonomies. Or you could say they are dynamic taxonomies that are manually created by the user in the back-end. Still, all the same, custom taxonomy rules apply.

You can see the [source code here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/87c6ca5ae0a5ba068cf78f924f494b2d146583c8/includes/class-wc-post-types.php#L187) which loops through the attributes and runs [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) on each. So to create a new attribute (remember it is just a taxonomy) then you need to run `register_taxonomy()` and simple prepend `pa_` to the start of the taxonomy name.

Mimicking some of the values of the taxonomy args from core would get you something like this for a 'Colors' attribute.

```
/**
 * Register a taxonomy.
 */
function so_29549525_register_attribute() {

    $permalinks = get_option( 'woocommerce_permalinks' );

    $taxonomy_data = array(
                        'hierarchical'          => true,
                        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
                        'labels'                => array(
                                'name'              => __( 'My Colors', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'singular_name'     => __( 'Color', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'search_items'      => __( 'Search colors', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'all_items'         => __( 'All colors', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent color', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent color:', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit color', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'update_item'       => __( 'Update color', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add new color', 'your-textdomain' ),
                                'new_item_name'     => __( 'New color', 'your-textdomain' )
                            ),
                        'show_ui'           => false,
                        'query_var'         => true,
                        'rewrite'           => array(
                            'slug'         => empty( $permalinks['attribute_base'] ) ? '' : trailingslashit( $permalinks['attribute_base'] ) . sanitize_title( 'colors' ),
                            'with_front'   => false,
                            'hierarchical' => true
                        ),
                        'sort'              => false,
                        'public'            => true,
                        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                        'capabilities'      => array(
                            'manage_terms' => 'manage_product_terms',
                            'edit_terms'   => 'edit_product_terms',
                            'delete_terms' => 'delete_product_terms',
                            'assign_terms' => 'assign_product_terms',
                        )
                    );

  register_taxonomy( 'pa_my_color', array('product'), $taxonomy_data );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_register_taxonomy', 'so_29549525_register_attribute' );
```

**Update 2020-11-18**

Attribute taxonomies are stored in the `{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` database table. And from there WooCommerce runs `register_taxonomy()` on each one that's found in the table. So in order to create an attribute taxonomy, a row should be added to this table. WooCommerce has a function [`wc_create_attribute()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php#L466) that will handle this for us. (Since 3.2+).

My conditional logic to test if the attribute exists is not the greatest and I would advise using some kind of version option in your plugin's update routine. But as an example of using `wc_create_taxonomy()` this should insert an attribute called "My Color".

```
/**
 * Register an attribute taxonomy.
 */
function so_29549525_create_attribute_taxonomies() {

    $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

    $slugs = wp_list_pluck( $attributes, 'attribute_name' );

    if ( ! in_array( 'my_color', $slugs ) ) {

        $args = array(
            'slug'    => 'my_color',
            'name'   => __( 'My Color', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'type'    => 'select',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives'  => false,
        );

        $result = wc_create_attribute( $args );

    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'so_29549525_create_attribute_taxonomies' );
```

Comment: no, it will creates value for EXISTING attribute. 
I need create my own pa_**** elements

Comment: Then you need to `register_taxonomy()`. See the edit.

Comment: @helgatheviking is there other way to create woocommerce attribute other than using register_taxonomy? register_taxonomy uses too much resource and i can't use it because im create products and attributes programmatically.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez WooCommerce attributes *are* WordPress taxonomies, so you need `register_taxonomy()`. As a possible alternative you *might* be able to use the API? But I'm not sure.

Comment: seems like I dont have other ways but only use custom attribute.I thought there might be a hack for register_taxonomy

Comment: I don't think this works in WC 3+ anymore. It does register a Taxonomy, but doesn't link it to WC Attributes.

Comment: @ggedde well it is 5 years old. :) Looking at `wc_get_attribute_taxonomies()` I believe attribute taxonomies are stored in the `{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` and can be filtered via [`woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php#L73). Looks like LoicTheAztec has the insert row into the attributes table covered in his answer, but it appears that you can call `wc_create_attribute()` instead of duplicating the function.

Comment: I was not able to insert an attribute by filtering `woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` since other areas of Woo need this to have an ID that exists in the database table.

Comment: @helgatheviking can I create a new `taxonomy` attribute for products and then attach it to all existing products directly with `SQL QUERY`?

Comment: Probably? I believer everything is possible given enough time/resources! don't know _how_ to do that though myself.

Answer (score 9):

> **2023 Update** for Woocommerce 3.2 | Still works on WC 8.1+
> Not to be used in a Multisite environment

To create a new product attribute from a label name use the following function:

```
function create_product_attribute( $label_name ){
    $slugs = wp_list_pluck( wc_get_attribute_taxonomies(), 'attribute_name' );
    $slug  = sanitize_title( $label_name );

    if ( ! in_array( $slug, $slugs ) ) {
        $data = array(
            'name'         => $label_name,
            'slug'         => $slug,
            'type'         => 'select',
            'orderby'      => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives' => false,
        );

        return wc_create_attribute( $data );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

*Update based on **@helgatheviking** last update code*

---

Old answer: for WooCommerce 3+ (2018) | Not to be used in a Multisite environment

```
function create_product_attribute( $label_name ){
    global $wpdb;

    $slug = sanitize_title( $label_name );

    if ( strlen( $slug ) >= 28 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_product_attribute_slug_too_long', sprintf( __( 'Name "%s" is too long (28 characters max). Shorten it, please.', 'woocommerce' ), $slug ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    } elseif ( wc_check_if_attribute_name_is_reserved( $slug ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_product_attribute_slug_reserved_name', sprintf( __( 'Name "%s" is not allowed because it is a reserved term. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce' ), $slug ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    } elseif ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $label_name ) ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_product_attribute_slug_already_exists', sprintf( __( 'Name "%s" is already in use. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce' ), $label_name ), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    }

    $data = array(
        'attribute_label'   => $label_name,
        'attribute_name'    => $slug,
        'attribute_type'    => 'select',
        'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'attribute_public'  => 0, // Enable archives ==> true (or 1)
    );

    $results = $wpdb->insert( "{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $data );

    if ( is_wp_error( $results ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'cannot_create_attribute', $results->get_error_message(), array( 'status' => 400 ) );
    }

    $id = $wpdb->insert_id;

    do_action('woocommerce_attribute_added', $id, $data);

    wp_schedule_single_event( time(), 'woocommerce_flush_rewrite_rules' );

    delete_transient('wc_attribute_taxonomies');
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

Based on:

- Product Attribute [`wc_create_attribute()` function](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_create_attribute.html) code (Woocommerce 3.2+).
- [Create programmatically a variable product and two new attributes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054)

> **Related:** [Create programmatically a product using CRUD methods in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937409/create-programmatically-a-product-using-crud-methods-in-woocommerce-3/52941994#52941994)

Comment: Seems to keep creating duplicate taxonomies for me. Seems like the `taxonomy_exists` check is not working.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is there some reason why a new attribute is showing only when I delete another attribute? In code is delete_transient for wc_attribute_taxonomies but doesn't work like it should. Cache on page is disabled