# How to create WooCommerce new product attributes programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a possibility in WooCommerce to create attributes programmatically?

Here is a Example URL for the manually way:

www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes

---

The question is:

How to create new product attributes programmatically?

The question is not:

How to add values from existing product attributes to products?

jMike

Comment: Hope this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549525/woocommerce-create-new-attributes-programmatically

Comment: Sorry, I want create new product attributes and not add values from existing product attributes to products.