# Adding Attributes for variations woocommerce taxonomy only works the second time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a plugin to import variable products on woocommerce.

I'm trying to create attributes to work with. So, I use this function to create the taxonomies

```
process_add_attribute(array('attribute_name' => 'color', 'attribute_label' => 'Color', 'attribute_type' => 'text', 'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order', 'attribute_public' => false));

function process_add_attribute($attribute)
{
    global $wpdb;
//      check_admin_referer( 'woocommerce-add-new_attribute' );

    if (empty($attribute['attribute_type'])) { $attribute['attribute_type'] = 'text';}
    if (empty($attribute['attribute_orderby'])) { $attribute['attribute_orderby'] = 'menu_order';}
    if (empty($attribute['attribute_public'])) { $attribute['attribute_public'] = 0;}

    if ( empty( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) || empty( $attribute['attribute_label'] ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', __( 'Please, provide an attribute name and slug.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    } elseif ( ( $valid_attribute_name = valid_attribute_name( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) && is_wp_error( $valid_attribute_name ) ) {
        return $valid_attribute_name;
    } elseif ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', sprintf( __( 'Slug "%s" is already in use. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce' ), sanitize_title( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) );
    }

    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );

    do_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', $wpdb->insert_id, $attribute );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
    delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );

    return true;
}
```

This creates the taxonomies and I can see them in Products->Attributes.
But if I create a script that first creates the taxonomies and them try to add a term to them (working with parent product) using:

```
$var test = wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $avail_color, 'pa_color', true);
```

where $post_id is the id of the recently created product post, $avail_color is an array with {'red','blue'} and 'pa_color' is the name of the created taxonomy.

First time I run it text gives me invalid taxonomy error. But if I run it twice it works well and insert the terms into the pa_color taxonomy. (Notice that second time the script runs the tax is not created because it already exits).

I'm thinking about some kind of flush that must be done but I can't find how to fix it...

Comment: It does the same, works the second time the script runs. The attribute taxonomy is created but not the terms. Second time you run the script the values are added...

Comment: Well, someone wrote a comment here and them deleted it with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054

Comment: Managed to do it by creating the attributes taxonomies on plugin activation so when I add product variations terms are added. (I know what attributes I need so I can create them on plugin activation, but still looking for a better way to do it)