# Woocommerce get product attribute ID using name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I want to get the ID of a Woocommerce product attribute using the attribute name. e.g. `pa_foobar`

I know that product attributes are taxonomies, but get_taxonomy() doesn't return the taxonomy ID. I can't find a Woocommerce function that does this.

Comment: This has already been answered in [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec not true, you can't find best solution there (to use `wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name('pa_foobar')`).

Comment: @ArturCzyżewski Sorry, but the custom function [`get_attribute_id_from_name()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054) is a bit lighter than the woocommerce official one, and answers this question too… So yes it's answered before... I could have close this thread as duplicated, which I have not done, to allow people to answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($taxonomy_name)`.

Comment: Hi! Please explain why this is a solution to OPs code as code only answers are discouraged on SO. This would help OP and future visitors to the site. Thanks!

Comment: That is a function that can allow you to get an attribute's id by name. Usually,

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce stores attributes in the table `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`. Querying the database directly is not recommended but I was able to get the attribute ID using this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$attribute_id = $wpdb->get_var("select attribute_id from {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies where attribute_name='pa_foobar'");
```

Comment: Yes that SQL query is similar to the one used in my custom function `get_attribute_id_from_name()` on [**this answer thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054) … +1

Answer (score -2):

You can use that

> > woocommerce_get_product_terms
> >
> > or
> >
> > get_the_terms()

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

```
 global $product;
 $id = $product->get_id();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I want to get a product attribute ID, not a product ID. At this point the attribute might not even be assigned to a product.

Comment: The two functions you have mentioned above do not return the product attribute ID. They return attribute terms.

Comment: Have you seen this 
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

Comment: What if the attribute is not yet assigned to a product?