# Programmatically a variable product and two attributes and terms in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a varible product with attributes and terms but its not working.

Here is my code

```
  create_product_variation( array(
        'author'        => '', // optional
        'title'         => 'Woo special one',
        'content'       => '<p>This is the product content <br>A very nice product, soft and clear…<p>',
        'excerpt'       => 'The product short description…',
        'regular_price' => '16', // product regular price
        'sale_price'    => '', // product sale price (optional)
        'stock'         => '10', // Set a minimal stock quantity
        'image_id'      => '', // optional
        'gallery_ids'   => array(), // optional
        'sku'           => '', // optional
        'tax_class'     => '', // optional
        'weight'        => '', // optional
        // For NEW attributes/values use NAMES (not slugs)
        'attributes'    => array(
            'Attribute 1'   =>  array( 'Value 1', 'Value 2' ),
            'Attribute 2'   =>  array( 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3' ),
        ),
    ) );


function save_product_attribute_from_name( $name, $label='', $set=true ){
    if( ! function_exists ('get_attribute_id_from_name') ) return;

    global $wpdb;

    $label = $label == '' ? ucfirst($name) : $label;
    $attribute_id = get_attribute_id_from_name( $name );

    if( empty($attribute_id) ){
        $attribute_id = NULL;
    } else {
        $set = false;
    }
    $args = array(
        'attribute_id'      => $attribute_id,
        'attribute_name'    => $name,
        'attribute_label'   => $label,
        'attribute_type'    => 'select',
        'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'attribute_public'  => 0,
    );


    if( empty($attribute_id) ) {
        $wpdb->insert(  "{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $args );
        set_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies', false );
    }

    if( $set ){
        $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
        $args['attribute_id'] = get_attribute_id_from_name( $name );
        $attributes[] = (object) $args;
        //print_r($attributes);
        set_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies', $attributes );
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

/**
 * Get the product attribute ID from the name.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param string $name | The name (slug).
 */
function get_attribute_id_from_name( $name ){
    global $wpdb;
    $attribute_id = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT attribute_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
    WHERE attribute_name LIKE '$name'");
    return reset($attribute_id);
}

/**
 * Create a new variable product (with new attributes if they are).
 * (Needed functions:
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param array $data | The data to insert in the product.
 */

function create_product_variation( $data ){
    if( ! function_exists ('save_product_attribute_from_name') ) return;

    $postname = sanitize_title( $data['title'] );
    $author = empty( $data['author'] ) ? '1' : $data['author'];

    $post_data = array(
        'post_author'   => $author,
        'post_name'     => $postname,
        'post_title'    => $data['title'],
        'post_content'  => $data['content'],
        'post_excerpt'  => $data['excerpt'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'ping_status'   => 'closed',
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'guid'          => home_url( '/product/'.$postname.'/' ),
    );

    // Creating the product (post data)
    $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variable object and save it
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
    $product->save();

    ## ---------------------- Other optional data  ---------------------- ##
    ##     (see WC_Product and WC_Product_Variable setters methods)

    // THE PRICES (No prices yet as we need to create product variations)

    // IMAGES GALLERY
    if( ! empty( $data['gallery_ids'] ) && count( $data['gallery_ids'] ) > 0 )
        $product->set_gallery_image_ids( $data['gallery_ids'] );

    // SKU
    if( ! empty( $data['sku'] ) )
        $product->set_sku( $data['sku'] );

    // STOCK (stock will be managed in variations)
    $product->set_stock_quantity( $data['stock'] ); // Set a minimal stock quantity
    $product->set_manage_stock(true);
    $product->set_stock_status('');

    // Tax class
    if( empty( $data['tax_class'] ) )
        $product->set_tax_class( $data['tax_class'] );

    // WEIGHT
    if( ! empty($data['weight']) )
        $product->set_weight(''); // weight (reseting)
    else
        $product->set_weight($data['weight']);

    $product->validate_props(); // Check validation

    ## ---------------------- VARIATION ATTRIBUTES ---------------------- ##

    $product_attributes = array();

    foreach( $data['attributes'] as $key => $terms ){
        $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($key); // The taxonomy slug
        $attr_label = ucfirst($key); // attribute label name
        $attr_name = ( wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($key)); // attribute slug

        // NEW Attributes: Register and save them
        if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
            save_product_attribute_from_name( $attr_name, $attr_label );

        $product_attributes[$taxonomy] = array (
            'name'         => $taxonomy,
            'value'        => '',
            'position'     => '',
            'is_visible'   => 0,
            'is_variation' => 1,
            'is_taxonomy'  => 1
        );

        foreach( $terms as $value ){
            $term_name = ucfirst($value);
            $term_slug = sanitize_title($value);

            // Check if the Term name exist and if not we create it.
            if( ! term_exists( $value, $taxonomy ) )
                wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy, array('slug' => $term_slug ) ); // Create the term

            // Set attribute values
            wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $term_name, $taxonomy, true );
        }
    }
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes );
    $product->save(); // Save the data
}
```

This is based on answer from [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce)

I am facing two issue here

1. its creating Attribute 2  only without their values
2. Attribute  is not getting assigned to product
3. set_transient seems not working properly in first attempt

Any idea

Answer (score 0):

As I am checking your code, we have done few changes now it's working as excepted.

**Source code**

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'create_custom_product_attribute' );

function create_custom_product_attribute(){
    
    create_product_variation( array(
        'author'        => '', // optional
        'title'         => 'Woo special one',
        'content'       => '<p>This is the product content <br>A very nice product, soft and clear…<p>',
        'excerpt'       => 'The product short description…',
        'regular_price' => '16', // product regular price
        'sale_price'    => '', // product sale price (optional)
        'stock'         => '10', // Set a minimal stock quantity
        'image_id'      => '', // optional
        'gallery_ids'   => array(), // optional
        'sku'           => '', // optional
        'tax_class'     => '', // optional
        'weight'        => '', // optional
        // For NEW attributes/values use NAMES (not slugs)
        'attributes'    => array(
            'Attribute 1'   =>  array( 'Value1', 'Value2' ),
            'Attribute 2'   =>  array( 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3' ),
        ),
    ) );
}


/**
 * Create a new variable product (with new attributes if they are).
 * (Needed functions:
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param array $data | The data to insert in the product.
 */

function create_product_variation( $data ){
    if( ! function_exists ('add_custom_attribute') ) return;

    $postname = sanitize_title( $data['title'] );
    $author = empty( $data['author'] ) ? '1' : $data['author'];

    $post_data = array(
        'post_author'   => $author,
        'post_name'     => $postname,
        'post_title'    => $data['title'],
        'post_content'  => $data['content'],
        'post_excerpt'  => $data['excerpt'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'ping_status'   => 'closed',
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'guid'          => home_url( '/product/'.$postname.'/' ),
    );

    // Creating the product (post data)
    $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variable object and save it
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
    $product->save();

    ## ---------------------- Other optional data  ---------------------- ##
    // IMAGES GALLERY
    if( ! empty( $data['gallery_ids'] ) && count( $data['gallery_ids'] ) > 0 )
        $product->set_gallery_image_ids( $data['gallery_ids'] );

    // SKU
    if( ! empty( $data['sku'] ) )
        $product->set_sku( $data['sku'] );

    // STOCK (stock will be managed in variations)
    $product->set_stock_quantity( $data['stock'] ); // Set a minimal stock quantity
    $product->set_manage_stock(true);
    $product->set_stock_status('');

    // Tax class
    if( empty( $data['tax_class'] ) )
        $product->set_tax_class( $data['tax_class'] );

    // WEIGHT
    if( ! empty($data['weight']) )
        $product->set_weight(''); // weight (reseting)
    else
        $product->set_weight($data['weight']);

    $product->validate_props(); // Check validation

    ## ---------------------- VARIATION ATTRIBUTES ---------------------- ##
    $product_attributes = array();

    foreach( $data['attributes'] as $key => $terms ){
        $attr_name = ucfirst($key);
        $attr_slug = sanitize_title($key);
        $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name(wp_unslash($key));
        // NEW Attributes: Register and save them
        
        if (taxonomy_exists($taxonomy))
        {
            $attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($attr_slug);   
        }else{
            $attribute_id = add_custom_attribute($attr_name);
        }
        
        $product_attributes[$taxonomy] = array (
            'name'         => $taxonomy,
            'value'        => '',
            'position'     => '',
            'is_visible'   => 0,
            'is_variation' => 1,
            'is_taxonomy'  => 1
        );

        if($attribute_id){
            // Iterating through the variations attributes
            foreach ($terms as $term_name )
            {
                $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attr_slug; // The attribute taxonomy
        
                // If taxonomy doesn't exists we create it (Thanks to Carl F. Corneil)
                if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ){
                    register_taxonomy(
                        $taxonomy,
                    'product_variation',
                        array(
                            'hierarchical' => false,
                            'label' => $attr_name,
                            'query_var' => true,
                            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $attr_slug), // The base slug
                        ),
                    );
                }
        
                // Check if the Term name exist and if not we create it.
                if( ! term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) ){
                    wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy ); // Create the term
                }
                //$term_slug = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->slug; // Get the term slug

                // Get the post Terms names from the parent variable product.
                $post_term_names =  wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );

                // Check if the post term exist and if not we set it in the parent variable product.
                if( ! in_array( $term_name, $post_term_names ) )
                    wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $term_name, $taxonomy, true );

                // Set the attribute data in the product variation
                //update_post_meta($variation_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $term_slug );
            }
        }
    }
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes ); 
    $product->save(); // Save the data
}

/*
* Register a global woocommerce product add attribute Class.
*
* @param str   $nam | name of attribute
* @param arr   $vals | array of variations
* 
*/
function add_custom_attribute($nam){

    $attrs = array();      
    $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies(); 

    $slug = sanitize_title($nam);

    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        array_push($attrs,$attributes[$key]->attribute_name);                    
    } 

    if (!in_array( $nam, $attrs ) ) {          
        $args = array(
            'slug'    => $slug,
            'name'   => __( $nam, 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'    => 'select',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives'  => false,
        );                    
        return wc_create_attribute($args);
    }               
}
```

Now you can change **add_action** and **attribute value** accordingly.

**Attribute Page:**
[image]

**Product Page:**
[image]

Answer (score -2):

## Final Solution

Creating attributes with [`wc_create_attribute`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-attribute-functions.html#function_wc_create_attribute), and then we explicitly registering taxonomies solves the problem:

```
/**
 * Create a new global attribute if doesn't exist.
 *
 * @since 3.2.0
 * @param string $name | Name of the attribute.
 * @param string $label | Label of the attribute.
 */
function create_global_attribute($name, $label = '') {
    $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

    $slugs = wp_list_pluck( $attributes, 'attribute_name' );

    if ( ! in_array( $name, $slugs ) ) {

        $args = array(
            'slug'          => wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( $name ),
            'name'          => ! empty( $label ) ? $label : ucfirst( $name ),
            'type'          => 'select',
            'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
            'has_archives'  => false,
        );

        $result = wc_create_attribute( $args );

    }
}

/**
 * Create a new variable product (with new attributes if they are).
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param array $data | The data to insert in the product.
 */
function create_product_variation( $data ){
    if( ! function_exists ( 'create_global_attribute' ) ) return;

    $postname = sanitize_title( $data['title'] );
    $author = empty( $data['author'] ) ? '1' : $data['author'];

    $post_data = [
        'post_author'   => $author,
        'post_name'     => $postname,
        'post_title'    => $data['title'],
        'post_content'  => $data['content'],
        'post_excerpt'  => $data['excerpt'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'ping_status'   => 'closed',
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'guid'          => home_url( '/product/'.$postname.'/' ),
    ];

    // Creating the product (post data)
    $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variable object and save it
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
    $product->save();

    ## ---------------------- Other optional data  ---------------------- 
    ##
    ##     (see WC_Product and WC_Product_Variable setters methods)

    // THE PRICES (No prices yet as we need to create product variations)

    // IMAGES GALLERY
    if( ! empty( $data['gallery_ids'] ) && count( $data['gallery_ids'] ) > 0 )
        $product->set_gallery_image_ids( $data['gallery_ids'] );

    // SKU
    if( ! empty( $data['sku'] ) )
        $product->set_sku( $data['sku'] );

    // STOCK (stock will be managed in variations)
    $product->set_stock_quantity( $data['stock'] ); // Set a minimal stock quantity
    $product->set_manage_stock( true );
    $product->set_stock_status('');

    // Tax class
    if( empty( $data['tax_class'] ) )
        $product->set_tax_class( $data['tax_class'] );

    // WEIGHT
    if( ! empty( $data['weight'] ) )
        $product->set_weight(''); // weight (reseting)
    else
        $product->set_weight( $data['weight'] );

    $product->validate_props(); // Check validation

    ## ---------------------- VARIATION ATTRIBUTES ---------------------- 
    ##

    $product_attributes = array();

    foreach( $data['attributes'] as $key => $terms ){
        $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $key ); // The taxonomy slug

        // NEW Attributes: Create if doesn't exist and register taxonomy
        if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
            create_global_attribute( $key, $key );
            register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, array('product'), array(
                'type'    => 'select',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'public'  => 0,
            ));
        }

        $product_attributes[$taxonomy] = [
            'name'         => $taxonomy,
            'value'        => '',
            'position'     => '',
            'is_visible'   => 0,
            'is_variation' => 1,
            'is_taxonomy'  => 1
        ];

        foreach( $terms as $value ){
            $term_name = ucfirst($value);
            $term_slug = sanitize_title($value);

            // Check if the Term name exist and if not we create it.
            if( ! term_exists( $value, $taxonomy ) ) {
                wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy, ['slug' => $term_slug] ); // Create the term
            }

            // Set attribute values
            wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $term_name, $taxonomy, true );
        }
    }
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes );
    $product->save(); // Save the data
}
```

### Regarding adding atributes in your code

The `wc_get_attribute_taxonomies` retrieves the last added attribute because you add the taxonomy incorrectly, namely you don't register it but only insert directly to the DB, so the transient `wc_attribute_taxonomies` contains the last added attribute:

```
...
if( empty($attribute_id) ) {
    /**
     * New taxonomy inserts directly here 
     * without getting registered in $wp_taxonomies 
     */
    $wpdb->insert(  "{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $args );
    set_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies', false );
}

if( $set ){
    $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    /**
     * Here $attributes containes the last attribute 
     * because the wc_get_attribute_taxonomies
     * fetches the cached value.
     * @see https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-attribute-functions.html#source-view.55
     */
    $args['attribute_id'] = get_attribute_id_from_name( $name );
    $attributes[] = (object) $args;
    set_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies', $attributes );
} else {
    return;
}
...
```

You can fetch the attributes [directly from the database as Woocommerce does in the mentioned function](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-attribute-functions.html#source-view.63), so the code would be:

```
...
if( empty($attribute_id) ) {
    /**
     * New taxonomy inserts directly here 
     * without getting registered in $wp_taxonomies 
     */
    $wpdb->insert(  "{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $args );
    set_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies', false );
}

if( $set ){
    $attributes = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies WHERE attribute_name != '' ORDER BY attribute_name ASC;" );
    $args['attribute_id'] = get_attribute_id_from_name( $name );
    $attributes[] = (object) $args;
    set_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies', $attributes );
} else {
    return;
}
...
```

### Regarding adding terms in your code

the `wp_insert_term` returns WP_Error when checks the taxonomy for this term exists. Even though you insert new taxonomy here:

```
$wpdb->insert(  "{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $args );
```

as I said before, you do that directly, without registering it in `$wp_taxonomies` that's why it doesn't add new terms:

```
// Check if the Term name exist and if not we create it.
if( ! term_exists( $value, $taxonomy ) )
    wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy, array('slug' => $term_slug ) );
    /**
     * wp_insert_term checks the given $taxonomy exists using taxonomy_exists()
     * @see https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2280
     * in turn taxonomomy_exists() checks it within $wp_taxonomies
     * @see https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L309
     */
```