# woocommerce: product attribute will not add value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm programmatically creating attribute variations (variable product). Everything I've seen does this easily, but the value simply does not show up. Here's my code:

```
$thedata = Array(
     'pa_performance_dates' =>  Array( 
          'name'        => 'pa_performance_dates', 
           'value'      =>  $arrayOfTermIDs,
           'position'   => 1,
           'is_visible' => '1',
           'is_variation' => '1',
           'is_taxonomy' => '1'
      )
);
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $thedata );
```

Attribute: "Performance Dates" WORKING
Attribute Values (terms under attribute): "1571986800" WORKING
Attribute Values being added under the Product ID: NOT WORKING

[image: attribute values still empty]

I have tried everything: setting the VALUE above to an array of the terms slugs, an array of the IDs, a simple string of an ID or slug/value. Nothing works. 
I've also followed these stackoverflow questions: 
[woocommerce: add value to a product attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518878/woocommerce-add-value-to-a-product-attribute)
[Creating WooCommerce product variation adds an empty attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657703/creating-woocommerce-product-variation-adds-an-empty-attribute-value)
[Add Product Attributes with values to a product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748657/add-product-attributes-with-values-to-a-product-in-woocommerce)

I've also tested the product_id variable and that is correctly showing the ID of the post.

**What am I doing wrong?!?!?!?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add value to an attribute of a product use `wp_set_object_terms`

For example: `$arrayOfTermIDs = array( 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3' );`

```
foreach ($arrayOfTermIDs as $arrayOfTermID) {
    $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $arrayOfTermID, 'pa_performance_dates', true );          
}
```

To append the value set the last argument as `true` or set it to `false` to overwrite.

Comment: @KimberlyFox Happy to help.