# Add woocommerce attribute and values in database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-database

I want to add attribute to woocommerce via database directly. For that I create a new term in wp_terms and add new taxonomies in wp_term_taxonomies with term_id added above and slug with pa_ prefix.
Also add attribute in woocommerce_attribute_taxonomy.

But the added attribute doesn't show in products>attributes dashboard.

What should I do more after adding term and term_taxonomy?

Comment: see [Create programmatically a variable product and two new attributes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054) and [Create new product attribute programmatically in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549525/create-new-product-attribute-programmatically-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec but I want to know what happens in db. I want to add attribute by pure php not using wpdb in WordPress code.

Comment: If you go through the code you will see what happens in database. Each function that create set or update do a SQL query. In your case, you certainly missed saving cached data (transient)…

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec. I'll check that .