# Create product attribute programmatically in Woocommerce on multisite environement

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to add product attributes programmatically like so:

[Create new product attribute programmatically in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549525/create-new-product-attribute-programmatically-in-woocommerce)

but have problem that attributes are adding on all sites and also duplicating on refresh, my example code:

```
$domain = "some domain name";

if ($domain) {

function create_product_attribute($label_name)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $slug = sanitize_title($label_name);

    if (strlen($slug) >= 28) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_product_attribute_slug_too_long', sprintf(__('Name "%s" is too long (28 characters max). Shorten it, please.', 'woocommerce'), $slug), array('status' => 400));
    } elseif (wc_check_if_attribute_name_is_reserved($slug)) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_product_attribute_slug_reserved_name', sprintf(__('Name "%s" is not allowed because it is a reserved term. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce'), $slug), array('status' => 400));
    }

    if (taxonomy_exists($label_name)) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_product_attribute_slug_already_exists', sprintf(__('Name "%s" is already in use. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce'), $label_name), array('status' => 400));
    }

    $data = array(
        'attribute_label'   => $label_name,
        'attribute_name'    => $slug,
        'attribute_type'    => 'select',
        'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'attribute_public'  => 0,
    );

    $results = $wpdb->insert("{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $data);

    if (is_wp_error($results)) {
        return new WP_Error('cannot_create_attribute', $results->get_error_message(), array('status' => 400));
    }

    $id = $wpdb->insert_id;

    do_action('woocommerce_attribute_added', $id, $data);

    wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'woocommerce_flush_rewrite_rules');

    delete_transient('wc_attribute_taxonomies');
}

create_product_attribute('test_atribute9');

}
```

and result: https://prnt.sc/HPateXfTUPzD on each site from multisite

Thanks for help

Comment: WooCommerce is not really made to be installed on a multisite environment, or it's not recommended to use it in a multisite environmen. **Most of all WooCommerce threads in Stack overflow doesn't handle multisite environment**, as most Woocommerce developers (or coders) doesn't face this problem (meaning doesn't work on multisite projects). Real e-commerce working sites that are successful doesn't run on a multisite environment for many reasons.

Comment: My answer code on [Create new product attribute programmatically in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549525/create-new-product-attribute-programmatically-in-woocommerce) has been updated, but I think that it still doesn't work for a multisite environment.

Comment: I will try, thanks. But interesting, that this wouldn't work even if function is limit only on specific page id...

Comment: This is about global custom taxonomy creation, so you need to look at multisite custom taxonomy creation for a sub-site to find out how to handle that.

Comment: I have limited execution to a specific blog ID, but the duplication issue still exists (with updated code) on page refresh ..

Answer (score 0):

I avoided duplicates by using a new function that checks if an attribute exists.

To target specific site from multisite we can achieve with "get_current_blog_id()"

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

if ($blog_id == 11) {


function attribute_exists_by_slug($slug) {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies';
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT attribute_id FROM $table_name WHERE attribute_name = %s", $slug);

    return $wpdb->get_var($query) !== null;
}

function create_product_attribute($label_name) {
    global $wpdb;

    $slug = sanitize_title($label_name);

   if (strlen($slug) >= 28) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_product_attribute_slug_too_long', sprintf(__('Name "%s" is too long (28 characters max). Shorten it, please.', 'woocommerce'), $slug), array('status' => 400));
    } elseif (wc_check_if_attribute_name_is_reserved($slug)) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_product_attribute_slug_reserved_name', sprintf(__('Name "%s" is not allowed because it is a reserved term. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce'), $slug), array('status' => 400));
    } elseif (attribute_exists_by_slug($slug)) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_product_attribute_slug_already_exists', sprintf(__('Name "%s" is already in use. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce'), $slug), array('status' => 400));
    }

    $data = array(
        'attribute_label'   => $label_name,
        'attribute_name'    => $slug,
        'attribute_type'    => 'select',
        'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'attribute_public'  => 0, // Enable archives ==> true (or 1)
    );

    $results = $wpdb->insert("{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $data);

    if (is_wp_error($results)) {
        return new WP_Error('cannot_create_attribute', $results->get_error_message(), array('status' => 400));
    }

    $id = $wpdb->insert_id;

    do_action('woocommerce_attribute_added', $id, $data);

    wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'woocommerce_flush_rewrite_rules');

    delete_transient('wc_attribute_taxonomies');
}


create_product_attribute('samp_attribute');
}
```